# Move .tmux and .tmuxinator directories

Tags: tmux, xdg

How can I move the `.tmux` and `.tmuxinator` directories from their default location (`$HOME`) to comply with the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)?

As these are configuration directories, I would expect them to reside under `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, which is usually `$HOME/.config`.

Comment: eh? Explain please. XDG does not do hidden files and is about user specific files. .tmux and .tmuxinator is not user specific. So what complaince are we talking about?  Besides that: moving those 2 will probably require you to recompile tmux since it will be expecting those directories.

Comment: @Rinzwind: My `.tmuxinator` and `.tmux` directories are most definitely user specific, cluttering up `$HOME` by default.

This question seeks to answer your "probably" ;)

Comment: `git` (for example) seems to disagree with you, It looks for it's configuration file in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`.

Comment: Again you are not interpreting things correctly git uses ... **"--local     For writing options: write to the repository .git/config file. This is the default behavior.:**  and `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` is the `Second user-specific configuration file` If not set `$HOME/.config/git/config` is used. And it also uses `~/.gitconfig`. tmux does not.

Comment: With respect to Tmuxinator, you can't - yet. There is [an open issue/feature request](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/360) for adding XDG support, though.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `tmux` nor `tmuxinator` currently support the XDG Base Dirs Spec.

The current state-of-play can be found at:

- `tmux` - https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/142
- `tmuxinator` - https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/360